# Use unit tests for a single project when I have multiple project folders in explorer?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytest

I have a main folder with different project folders:

```
├───2021
│       project_1
|               └───data
|               └───src
|               └───tests
|                       └───pytest.ini
|                           test_stuff_1.py
|       project_2
|               └───data
|               └───src
|               └───tests
|                       └───pytest.ini
|                           test_stuff_2.py
|       project_3
|               └───data
|               └───src
|               └───tests
|                       └───pytest.ini
|                           test_stuff_3.py
```

Folder "2021" is the folder I have open in the VS Code-Explorer so that I can easily switch between projects without having to reopen every project folder every time / limit myself to a single project folder.

But the VS Code testing button (the flask symbol) on the left sets the testing folder automatically to "2021" and does not find any tests.

How can I configure VS Code so that I can test each project individually when I have my "2021" folder open?

Comment: What if you create a Multi Root Workspace

Comment: @Vega, did you work this out? I'm trying to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Could you select `pytest` instead of `unittest` search?

```
"python.testing.pytestEnabled": true,
"python.testing.pytestArgs": ["."]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am running unittest rather than pytest, but I think that the discovery requirements are similar. I have a nearly identical folder structure. You need to have an __init__.py file in *every* folder in the path with tests to be discovered (2021, project_x, tests), and likely all of the src folders if you are importing anything from those folders.

Also, make sure that VSCode is told the correct pattern to search for, such as "test*.py".

In my case, I had empty __init__.py files in all folders except the tests folder (I forgot) and it wouldn't find the tests. When I added those files, it discovered the tests immediately.